# Python raw_input fails to work

Tags: python

I have seem to forgotten how to use python.. print is not printing the name? I think am confusing C syntax with python

```
name = raw_input("Enter your name")
print "welcome, %s" name
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed `%`. You need to be doing:

```
print "hello %s" %name
```

Using [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) is another way to go about it:

```
print "welcome, {}".format(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just forgot a `%` in there.

```
print "welcome, %s" % name
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a string you want to print with a variable, you have four options:

**Option 1: *Use percent***

```
name = raw_input("Enter your name")
print "Welcome, %s" % name
```

**Option 2: *Use `{}`***

```
name = raw_input("Enter your name")
print "Welcome, {}".format(name)
```

**Option 3: *Use a comma***

```
name = raw_input("Enter your name")
print "Welcome,", name
```

**Option 4: *Use a plus***

```
name = raw_input("Enter your name")
print "Welcome, "+name
```

Use a comma if the variable is at the end of the sentence, and use plus if it is in the middle.